Can I turn off the transmitter when receiving half-duplex SPI?
I have a STM32F103 Blue Pill-based interface board which is being used to translate from USB to a custom single-wire debugger interface (used by some Telink chips). I didn't write it, but I'm trying to make it work.
The implementation is using the STM32's SPI hardware to send and receive bits in full-duplex mode. MISO and MOSI are tied together:

SCLK is ignored completely. (The debugger interface is intended to be self-clocked, but as the STM32's SPI implementation doesn't support that, you need to configure the board's clock rate to match what the SPI interface expects; this seems really brittle. I haven't got to the point where this has become a problem yet.)
But, what's actually happening is this:

You can see the debugger sending a communication to the board. The target board is receiving it and is trying to reply, but you can see that it's unable to pull the debugger line down very far, and as a result the interface isn't picking up the response.
The way the interface works is that MISO is floating (without a pullup resistor) and MOSI is in push-pull mode. It's using the SPI hardware in full-duplex mode, so that it's transmitting the output packet while receiving the response at the same time. My belief is that it's doing this because the target board is replying the very instant the output packet is complete, meaning there's no time for code to run once the output packet is finished. The clock rate it's using is about 0.5us per SPI bit, which, if I've managed to arithmetic correctly is 2MHz. Because MISO and MOSI are tied together, the receiver is picking up the transmitting signal, but that's fine.
I think that what's happening here is that even when idle, MOSI is being driven high, and the target board doesn't have enough control authority to drive the signal low against the STM32's transistor.
So, in order to correctly receive the response, I need to somehow stop it doing this?
What I've tried:

configuring MOSI to open-drain mode. This produces a mangled waveform as when the signal level goes high, it doesn't rise quickly enough to produce a valid bit. Neither the STM32's receiver nor the target board can understand the result.

increasing the value of the resistor. This has no effect on the voltage of the target board's replies (which surprises me).


Things I've thought about:

bitbanging the GPIOs. This sounds really hard, because not only is there not much time between bits but the timing needs to be precise because everything's self-clocked. Experiments have shown that even a handful of instructions can lead to significant gaps in the output bitstream.

using the STM32's hardware in actual half-duplex mode, but this relies on the CPU manually changing the mode from Tx to Rx once the transmission is complete. In 0.5us? Unlike conventional half-duplex SPI, I don't control when the target device replies.

chaining together three DMAs: one to do the transmission, one to reconfigure the GPIO, and one to do the reception. This sounds... complicated.


Given the target clock speed is 2MHz it feels like doing anything is software in pushing things.
TBH, doing anything other than SPI half-duplex feels like code smell. But the original author didn't do this, and presumably had reasons. It'd be really nice if there was a way to tell the SPI system to switch from Tx mode to Rx mode automatically. Is there?

Double check if resistor value has no effect. Check if it is truly connected to MOSI.

Would you mind to [edit] your question to add a link to the documentation of SWS, please? This could help us understand the requirements of this interface. Currently your question has a smell of an XY problem.

Some ideas what to try... -- Experiment with bigger values for the series resistor. -- Replace the resistor with a diode that pulls low when MOSI is low, and use a pul-up resistor ar MISO.

When you configured MOSI as open-drain, did you add a pull-up resistor? (Please add such information to your question.)

The schematic seems incorrect. You may need to post a correct schematic. The pin configuration seems weird.

Half duplex mode will not work. During transmit MOSI is used to drive the SWS signal. During receive MOSI is high and makes the 750 ohm resistor work as a pullup on the SWS signal.
It would help if you could posted a schematic or photograph, not the github drawing, but the symptoms (resistor value not affecting the signal, and the approx 2.2 volt low signal in receive) suggest that the wires to A7 and A6 are connected swapped on the blue pill.

SPI communiation is full duplex which means you are sending something from the master over the SPI bus to get data from the slave. At any speed (clock speed) of the bus, the direction of bus is both ways. Your question has to be rephrased correctly. You cant turn off the master or the slave when SPI messages are in transit. Why do you use pull up resistors? Is it required for the slave? A schematic of your interface would be nice to see. Try to drive the pins in push pull mode just to have hassle free debugging. The STM CPU may have a feature to drive the MOSI and MISO pins low when idle instead of making them high with a pull up resistors. Pull up resistors are not needed unless you want to use a 1-wire interface.  The chip select signal is missing in the schematic and so is the CLK.  You also shorted SWS and another pin. It seems not correct as MOSI, MISO , CLK and CS signals should be separate.
